# File not found while running a sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am currently working in a shell script to automate some things (copying files and preserving their "change date"). I tested all commands on my shell, but when I run them on a script, they don't behave correctly.

If I run this o my shell, I get the appropriate result:

```
$> filename=/home/root/data/ABCD1234/20170123-231000.wav
$> echo "$filename"
/home/root/data/ABCD1234/20170123-231000.wav
$> cdate=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S -r $filename)
$> echo $cdate
201701232310.00
$> cp $filename $filename.bck 
touch -t $cdate $filename.bck
```

But when I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# list desired files
files=$(find /home/root/data/ABCD1234/*)

# iterate over every file found
for filename in $files
do
    echo "$filename"
    cdate=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S -r $filename)
    echo $cdate
    cp $filename $filename.bck 
    touch -t $cdate $filename.bck
done

exit 0
```

I get the following output (assuming there are 2 files in this folder)

```
/home/root/data/ABCD1234/20170123-231000.wav
': No such file or directory/data/ABCD1234/20170123-231000.wav

/home/root/data/ABCD1234/20170123-231500.wav
': No such file or directory/data/ABCD1234/20170123-231500.wav
```

PS: I am using an ARAGO distro and most shell commands are a redirect to BusyBox.

PS: In my original script I am not actually copying files, so keeping timestamp on the cp command won't solve my problem.

Comment: The assignment to `files` has an unbalanced `(`.

Comment: I recommend you to use -p option with cp to preserve timestamps.

Comment: Actuallly, on my original script I am zipping the file using gzip instead of copying, so the -p won't solve my problem. :-)

Comment: Are you trying to find _all files_ in the directory, or are you only interested in the `*.wav` file in the top level of the directory?

Comment: In my original script, am interested in some specific files, where I use a more elaborate "find" with regex. For the sake of this question, consider all files .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could only come from the "files" variable, since the script by @Kusalananda works perfectly when "find" is used to populate it.

It turns out that this string can have CR-LF instead of LF (the tool I used was a port from an Windows C++ program).

Removing the CR in the variable solved the problem. To remove, I used following line before the for loop

```
files=${files//[$'\t\r\n']}
```

Comment: I suggest you do not be shy and accept your own answer. By the way, the jammed error message kind of hints that this is a CR problem...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the quoting of the `$files` variable.  It will assign all the filenames *at once* to `filename`.

If you're just interested in the `*.wav` files in `/home/root/data/ABCD1234/`, you may do this instead:

```
for filename in /home/root/data/ABCD1234/*.wav
do
    echo "$filename"
    cdate="$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S -r "$filename" )"
    echo "$cdate"
    cp "$filename" "$filename.bck"
    touch -t "$cdate" "$filename.bck"
done
```

Using `find`:

```
find /home/root/data/ABCD1234/  other options  |
while read -r filename; do
  # loop as before
done
```

Comment: I removed the quotes in the "for filename in "$files" but i still get the same error. As for the files I need, I actually have a more elaborate "find" with regex, whose result is stored in the "files" variable. For the sake of this question, consider all files

Comment: @Jonas There is no need to store the filenames in a variable. See updated answer.

Comment: Your code without find works great. I get the point. But I want to know why the script doesn't work in the cases were I provide a variable containing several lines (where every line is a file path).

Comment: @Jonas Does it work if you double quote your `$filename` variable everywhere?

Comment: It didn't work using double quotes

Comment: @Jonas Then I suggest you use the `while` loop variation. That's the proper way of doing it anyway. If you find yourself reading in lots of data in a variable, you should stop and consider doing it some more efficient way anyway.

Comment: No, the problem is not with quoting. I have the same problem with a script that does not quote anything.